# How to style react-select component so that it is inline with some text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, react-select

I want to style my `react-select` component such that it looks like the below image (inline with the text).

[image]

I can do this easily using the normal `select` component inside a span and remove the border like this:

```
<select disabled={readOnlyMode} style={{ border: 'none' }}>
    <option default>Select response</option>
</select>
```

But I want to use react-select for this and unable to figure out what styling should I apply.

Answer (score 2):

`react-select` provides you with the ability to adjust the styles for the components. You can check it here: https://react-select.com/styles.

In your case, you should adjust `control` style key:

```
const customStyles = {
  control: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    border: 'none',
  }),
};
```

And pass `customStyles` as a `styles` prop in `react-select` component

Answer (score 0):

you can custom change the indicator using following code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";


class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const DropdownIndicator = (props) => {
    return (
      components.DropdownIndicator && (
        <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x30" />
        </components.DropdownIndicator>
        )
      );
    };
    return (
      <Select
        components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
        // pass other props
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

found this answer [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3493) and `react-select` styling documentations can be found [here](https://react-select.com/styles)